# Can Anyone Identify this Tissue?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, tissue, arthropod

I am hoping someone can identify the image below
[image]

My wife felt a bug bite her and found this in her hair now she's worried that it was a tick.
the photo is at 40X under microscope. I'm guessing it's an arthropod maybe some kind of beetle but I haven't seen anything like this before.

Comment: One usually doesn't feel tick bites. To me it looks like some kind of beetle too.